# Parse error with empty date from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I get a response from a webservice which contains `<EndDate/>`. The field has `minOccurs="0"` in WSDL.

```
<xsd:element name="EndDate" type="p8:Date" minOccurs="0">
```

When I look in Fiddler I see the data arrive, but VS crashes on parsing with the error:

> The string is not recognized as a valid DateTime

. 
Is this because of the empty `<EndDate/>`? It's not mandatory, but if it's there it needs to have a correct value, or at least that's what I think.
Correct? And is there a way to avoid this error? The webservice is added as a web reference in my solution.

The error is thrown in the reference.cs file generated by VS when you import the webservice.

Comment: Can we see the actual code that throws this exception?

Comment: And an example of the data going up :)

Comment: Can you add the definition of `p8:Date`? Which namespace does `p8` refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

`minOccurs="0"` means that *the element can be omitted altogether*. So, the following two options would be correct:

```
<SomeType>
   <StartDate>2015-01-01</StartDate>
</SomeType>

<SomeType>
   <StartDate>2015-01-01</StartDate>
   <EndDate>2015-01-02</EndDate>
</SomeType>
```

It does *not* mean that *an empty string* for `EndDate` becomes a valid entry. Thus, the following is *not* correct:

```
<SomeType>
   <StartDate>2015-01-01</StartDate>
   <EndDate></EndDate>        <!-- equivalent to <EndDate /> -->
</SomeType>
```

Test case: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=0c001ac9-de37-49a3-a676-f857300c3dfa-xsdvalidation

---

The correct solution in that case would be to notify the provider of your web service that their response does not match their xsd schema.